# Hibernate ManytoOne mapping deleting child when parent does not exists

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-one

I have one java class Specification which is getting deployed to Specs master table.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "SPECS_MASTER")
Specification 
{
    @Id
    @Column(name = "SPEC_ID")
    String specId;

    //other attribute
}

Another Class 

@Entity
@Table(name = "PRODUCT_SPECS")
public class SpecificationValue {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "NODE_SPECS_ID")
    private Integer specId;

    @ManyToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "SPEC_ID")
    private Specification specification;
    //other mappings and attribute
}
```

My problem here is when I am deleting a specification_value by hibernate, if Specs master does not exists than hibernate is not able to delete specification value entry, which is expected in this mapping.

I want to be able to delete specification values even if specs_master does not exits, is there any way I can do this?

Comment: How can you have a `SpecificationValue` referring to a non-exist `Specification` ? Even FK in DB won't let you do it.  If you are looking for way to mess around the DB value and not care about data consistency, probably Hibernate is suitable to you

Comment: and, just a recommendation, next time, make up a more consistent example when posting the question.  It is just confusing that your table, entity name and ID column are so inconsistent.

Comment: Yeah, i got my answer, I was looking for some thing like 
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "NODE_ID")
@NotFound(action=NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
private ProductDetails node;

Here is the documentation,
https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/NotFoundAction.html

May be i should have rephrased my question with relevant examples.

Thanks